# R Highlighting some of the boundaries (or borders) of the region in a shape file with spplot()

Tags: r, polygon, geospatial, shapefile

I am working on a shape file and like to highlight some of the boundaries (borders) of the regions (as figure 1):

[image]

Figure 1:  some but not all of the regions (borders) of the shape file are highlighted

(Source: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48721006/highlighted.png)

The highlighting is achieved with ArcMap. I can't figure out how to do the same with R (particularly with the `spplot()`). Any suggestions on this?

To get the shape file

```
library(sp)
library(maptools)

con <- url("http://gadm.org/data/rda/ZAF_adm2.RData")

print(load(con))

close(con)

plot(gadm)
```

Many thanks!

G

Answer (score 3):

What I would do: (1) plot the complete set; (2) take a subset; (3) plot the subset with a different line type. For subsetting shape files, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443372/simple-way-to-subset-spatialpolygonsdataframe-i-e-delete-polygons-by-attribut).

```
plot(gadm)

# check class and structure of the data
class(gadm)
head(gadm@data)

# take a subset based on ID_2
some_polygons = subset(gadm,ID_2>=38840 & ID_2<38850)
plot(some_polygons, add=T, border='cyan', lwd=2)
```