# How do I delete factor levels in a spatialpolygonsdataframe in R?

Tags: r, spatial, levels

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame with $Species as a factor variable and with 22 levels of prey species. 
I would like R to only consider 16 of these species and delete the other 6.

Any suggestions? Nothing on Stack Overflow has worked.

Comment: Could you please tell us what you have tried so far?

Comment: There are many ways to subset a SPDF. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443372/simple-way-to-subset-spatialpolygonsdataframe-i-e-delete-polygons-by-attribut) and [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spdplyr/vignettes/spdplyr.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but you can access the coordinates of a spacial polygon object by indexing it. So you extract the coordinates from the species you need and work with that.

```
map2 = readOGR(dsn = "path", "35MUE250GC_SIR")

coords.sp = map2@polygons[[i]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords #replace i for index
```